# Display image using browser's native "view image" behavior when browsing to web root

Tags: html, responsive-design

When the visitor navigates to `example.com`, I want them to remain at that top level web address while their browser behaves exactly as if they had navigated to `example.com/image.jpg`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Would you kindly explain what inspired the downvote? I'm happy to clarify my question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but at least to me, it is unclear exactly what you're asking. Maybe [edit] your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Center the image inside and  tag in its natural size in the middle of the page and give the page a black/gray background.

for the image's container - the tag you put the  tag in, probably your  or a  - you can give it the following styles

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```